# Android text over-enlarging text size

Tags: android, textview

I'm new to android and I'm working on this "About" page that is giving me some really weird behavior. It has text that when clicked expands and then collapses when clicked again. The collapsed text is of a larger size than the expanded text. When I click to expand, the text is waaay larger than even the larger expanded text and even when I go to collapse again the collapsed text keeps the huge text size too. (It changes the actual text content just fine)

The xml Textview

```
<TextView
            ...
            android:textSize="@dimen/About_filler"
            android:id="@+id/Stuff"
            android:text="@string/about_filler"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="collapseToggle"
            ...
/>
```

The method clicking calls

```
public void collapseToggle(View view){
    TextView text = (TextView) view;
    if( ! text.getText().equals(getString(R.string.about_filler))){ //if not collapsed
        text.setText(getString(R.string.about_filler));
        text.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.About_filler));
    }

    else if(text.getId() == R.id.Stuff){
        text.setText(getString(R.string.about_contents_Stuff));    
        text.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.About_contents));
    }
```

And the dimen folder

```
...
<dimen name="About_contents">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="About_filler">40sp</dimen>
```

I know there are a million better ways to implement this kind of thing but why this is happening is just killing me.

Comment: why don't you use  TextAppearance.Small or TextAppearance.Medium or TextAppearance.Large. What i would do is make two text view one for filter and one for content and in content filter i declare the size like this android:textSize="15sp" if i don't want to use the text sizes given above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `text.setTextSize(float size)` assumes you're passing the size in `SP` units, thus it's converting the `SP` to `PX` internally.

On the other hand `getResources().getDimension()` is returning the unit in `PX`, internally doing the conversion from whatever value you set.

So what's happening in your case

- you've set `20sp` in the `dimens.xml`
- `getDimension()` is returning say `100px` (depending on the screen)
- `setTextSize()` assumes you've set **`100sp`** and resizes it to something really HUUGE.

To fix just use the other option for `setTextSize()` that accepts units:
`text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.About_contents));`